# Append content of a file a another file on the FTP server in PHP server

Tags: php, php-7

Is this function in php that I can use for transfer a file remotely from one server to another? Such as

```
ftp_append( 
  resource $ftp, 
  string $remote_file, 
  string $local_file
  [, int $mode = FTP_IMAGE ]
)
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is your problem?

Comment: Yes, you can. But why haven't you tested it?

Comment: I want to pass my file remotely using php from one server to another..

Comment: In my case it does not show any warning and it do not working in my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use file_get_contents to get contents of a file, and then append it with file_put_contents:

```
<?php

$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$host = "localhost";
$file_from = "file_from.txt"
$file_to = "file_to.txt";

$file_from_contents = file_get_contents($file_from);

$result = file_put_contents("ftp://$username:$password@host/$file_to", $file_from_contents, FILE_APPEND);

if($result === false) {
echo "An error occured";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ftp_append` appends to a file on the FTP server and does create it if it does not exist.

If you need to add to a file repeatedly (e.g. a log) on the ftp server without having to worry about whether it was deleted or may not be overwritten and do not want to write the whole get-append-put logic yourself, you can use this function.